# Angular global variable - static readonly in service class vs const

Tags: angular, typescript

What should be preferred?

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService {
  static readonly VALIDITIES = new Map<number, string>([
     ...
  ]);

  ...
}
```

VS:

```
const Validities = new Map<number, string>([
   ...
]);


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService {}
```

I've used the first approach most of the time, but unfortunately I get the following error, when I try to combine two Maps. The error only appears in my jasmine unit tests!

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService {
  static readonly VALIDITIES = new Map<number, string>([
    [1, 'A'],
    [2, 'B'],
    [3, 'C'],
    [4, 'D']
  ]);

  static readonly VALIDITY_FILTERS = new Map<number, string>([
    [0, 'invalid'],
    ...Array.from(MyService.VALIDITIES.entries()), // XXXX
    [99, 'all']
  ]);

  ...
}
```

Error in the highlighted line (XXXX):

```
An error was thrown in afterAll
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'VALIDITIES')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'VALIDITIES')
```

What exactly is wrong with the code? What is the alternative for it?

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're receiving indicates that the VALIDITIES property is undefined when the code is being executed. This error occurs because the code is trying to access the VALIDITIES property before it has been defined.

In this case, the VALIDITY_FILTERS property is being defined in the same class as VALIDITIES, so you can safely assume that they are in the same lexical scope. However, because VALIDITY_FILTERS is a static property, it is defined before the class is instantiated. When the VALIDITY_FILTERS property is being defined, the VALIDITIES property is not yet defined, so trying to access it will result in an error.

Solution could be something like this:

```js
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  static readonly VALIDITIES = new Map<number, string>([
    [1, 'A'],
    [2, 'B'],
    [3, 'C'],
    [4, 'D']
  ]);

  static validityFilters(): Map<number, string> {
    return new Map<number, string>([
      [0, 'invalid'],
      ...Array.from(MyService.VALIDITIES.entries()),
      [99, 'all']
    ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the error indicated that `MyService` is `undefined` rather than the property since it says `Cannot read properties **of** undefined`

Comment: It makes sense, and it is related to what i wrote.

Comment: You are saying the property is undefined, I am saying whatever he is calling on `VALIDITIES` is undefined. He is probably doing something other than using `MyService.VALIDITIES` like mocking or something, which we can't comment on without seeing the actual test code.

Comment: If I replace the VALIDITY_FILTERS with the function above, everything works fine?!

Comment: Ok, but I don't get why VALIDITIES isn't already defined, when VALIDITY_FILTERS gets defined?

Comment: The issue here is not the order in which the properties are declared, but rather the way they are referenced. When the VALIDITY_FILTERS property is declared, it is trying to access the VALIDITIES property, but at that point, the class definition is still in progress and the VALIDITIES property has not yet been fully declared.

Comment: In this case, the error is caused by the fact that the VALIDITY_FILTERS property is a static property, and as such it is defined before the class itself is instantiated. When the VALIDITY_FILTERS property is defined, the class definition is still in progress and the VALIDITIES property is not yet available.